# Guava Cache get Deprecation

Tags: caching, guava

Currently *com.google.common.cache.Cache.get(Object)* is deprecated at **Guava 11.0.1** version. But I can't understand what should be used instead of it. JavaDocs are poor and not clear (for me, of course :) ) :

> **Deprecated**. *This method has been split out into the LoadingCache
>   interface, and will be removed from Cache in Guava release 12.0. Note
>   that CacheBuilder.build(CacheLoader) now returns a LoadingCache, so
>   this deprecation (migration) can be dealt with by simply changing the
>   type of references to the results of CacheBuilder.build(CacheLoader).*

Can you help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says to use interface `LoadingCache` instead of `Cache` in your code, the former has the method `get`. If you see guava 12, it actually doesn't have the method. Or I've missed your actual question?